# iptraf doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking

When I start `iptraf` it can't detect any of my network interfaces.  I have a suspicion that this is tied to Ubuntu's new naming scheme for network interfaces (mine is called `wlp112s0` instead of `wlan0`).  If I try to force with this:

`sudo iptraf -i wlp112s0`

I get this message in a red textbox:

> Specified interface not supported

Comment: Did you try `iptraf-ng`?

Comment: `iptraf-ng` works, so if you change your comment to an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by @Thomas, try `iptraf-ng`.

Comment: What's the difference between the two (other than one works and the other doesn't)? Is `iptraf-ng` a fork? Google results seem to use the names interchangably, and I can't find any info on who started `iptraf-ng`.

Answer (score 1):

After searching on some sites, I found the solution, type `iptraf -u`